# Slot filling in RASA form with ambiguous user uput

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

Playing around with RASA for the first time, I went into the case that I need to fill slots in a form where it is not possible to distinguish some of them based on the users input. Given the [formbot-example](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/tree/master/examples/formbot) imagine a second required, numerical slot, e.g. "num_children" besides the already existing "num_people" slot. RASA requests the correct slot, but then fills the other numerical slot with the users input.

What is the correct way to tell RASA which slot to fill?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Either use a common slot, e.g. `number` for both or
- Use a common entity `number` and use a custom action to set the correct slot based on the last intent.